# Why is a manifold called a manifold?

Tags: terminology, manifolds, differential-topology

Manifold in English means many and various. (https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/manifold)

How did this come to mean a topological manifold with a differentiable structure?

Comment: In German, Riemann called his idea many-times extended aggregates.

Comment: Dear Kenta, take a look at the following wikipedia page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_manifolds_and_varieties

Comment: I do not know, but I was assumed it was because a manifold can be thought of as many copies of Euclidean space put together.

Comment: " Riemann's original German term, Mannigfaltigkeit, which William Kingdon Clifford translated as "manifoldness". In his Göttingen inaugural lecture, "

Comment: I always wanted the term "fold" also have the meaning of "layer", so that the term "manifold" would suggest the fact that it is a envelope of tangent planes, 
but my dictionary continues to oppose my needs...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Aguirre, Foster, and Merali's *Questioning the Foundations of Physics*, the term "manifold" comes from the German term "Mannigfaltigkeit" used by Riemann, which he used to describe the set of possible values of a variable under several constraints, because the variable can have many values. English mathematician and philosopher William Kingdon Clifford then translated this to "manifoldness."

Answer (score 4):

Manifold is simply a fancy word for *variety* or *plurality*.

Before Riemannian (or non-Euclidean) geometry, only the flat kind of spaces was considered, aka Euclidean spaces, for each dimension. So, for instance, when a $2$-D space was concerned, it was only a flat plane and that was the only kind of space (same goes to $3$-D, etc.) Then Mathematicians (like Riemann) started to think of curved-kinds, which made an $n$-dimensional space no longer of a unique, flat kind but *variety* or *Mannigfaltigkeit* (ie, manifold in English) of dimension $n$.